# Analysing the data from the study on Jocks and Burnouts by Eckert

Tags: english, language-change, sociolinguistics

I have a question for those who are familiar with the study by Eckert. I got stuck trying to analyze the table (the screenshot is attached). Do you know what "Input" and "Sig." mean here? Thank you very much in advance!

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure but given the data, and the relative size of the sig. column's values I suspect sig. could be the standard degviation (sig. for sigma)

Comment: Or, "Sig." could abbreviate "significance", in which case it might be the p-value. It seems strange that some of these read .000 though — if the p-value were less than 0.001 I would expect more significant figures to be given.

Comment: @jogloran yeah none of these values would seem worth mentioning if it was significance. Tbh the .000 entries are also odd if it's standard deviation unless there's some very small sample sizes